# how to get the full screen image in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I displayed the image gallary .when I click on the image in the image gallary it will be displayed on the full screen .

```
Gallery g=(Gallery)findViewById(R.id.gallery);
            g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
            g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(sampledatabase.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); });
}}
```

Comment: where you stuck exactly?

Answer (score 1):

to let Activitty to open in full screen type this

```
getWindow().setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

And to remove the  title bar type this

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```